# Load existing excel file to edit in C#

Tags: c#, excel, solution

I want to load an existing macro enabled Excel file to edit in C#. When I say existing Excel file, I mean that I want to set a template that the user must start with.

I am stuck at the first step, loading the Excel file. I managed to add the file to the solution, so it pops up in solution explorer but I don't know how to edit it in C#.

Comment: Take a look at SpreadsheetLight.

Comment: Do I have to download this just to load a excel file for me to edit?

Comment: [Create/Read/Edit Advance Excel 2007/2010 Report in C#.Net using EPPlus](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/680421/Create-Read-Edit-Advance-Excel-Report-in)

Comment: This is third-party library for manipulating Excel files. Take a look on its official site.

Comment: @OcasoProtal Ive seen that, but I doesnt tell me how to loading an excel file on so i can edit with code. I dont want the user to be able to choose a file of their choice from dialog box, I want them to start with a specific excel file.

Comment: Then ignore the file selection dialog part and jump right in with the filename of the excel file: `var pck = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(yourFilename))`

Comment: okay thanks, do i have to do something to the file first? because I am getting a red underline under my  filename.xlsm. Also, there is a red underline under ExcelPackage too.

`var pck = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filename.xlsm))`

Comment: Please help i`ve been searching for hours on how to do this and i cant find how.

Comment: It would be better if you included the relevant code in your question. Use quotes for your filename:  `var pck = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"filename.xlsm")) ` See: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/680421/Create-Read-Edit-Advance-Excel-Report-in#10